# Django 'No file chosen' in FileInput

Tags: python, django, file-io

I have a project here. I am able to add photos through the /admin panel. I tried to create a form so that I can add a photo not by going thro' the admin panel.

I get an error of file chosen. I can't tell where my problem is.

My model

```
class Photos(models.Model):
    Photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='background',blank=True,null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-pk','Photo')
    def __str__(self):
        return('Photos')
```

My forms.py

```
class AddPhotosForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photos
        fields = ("Photo",)
    
        widgets = {
            "Photo":forms.FileInput(),}
```

My views.py

```
class AddPhotosView(CreateView):
    model = Contact
    form_class = AddPhotosForm
    template_name = "add_photo.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('photos')
```

urls.py

```
path('add_photo',AddPhotosView.as_view(), name='add_photo'),
```

My add_photo.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %} Add Photo {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<hr>
<article class="container" >
    <div class="btn-primary" style="padding:10px;border-radius:10px">Add Photo</div>
    <hr>

    <div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <form method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.media }}
          {{ form.as_p }}
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Add</button><br><hr>
      </div>
    </div>
</article>
 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: what kind of error you are facing

Comment: When I try to add a file it doesn't add it tells me no file exists on saving

Comment: what is use of model = Contact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add this to the form attributes `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, otherwise your `request.FILES` will be empty. This is used in all file models fields (`FileField, ImageField`)